# Divider is not visible in horizontal list view flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, divider

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: false,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
          return Center(
            child: Card(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: const [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                      width: 100,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: 10,topLeft: 10),
                          child: Text("admistraction")),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 2,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 5),
                        child: Text(
                          "Start Learning",
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 5);
  }
```

Divider horizontal line is not visible in list view.
I tried to wrap a divider in row or column I also wrap it in Container but its not working its working fine with vertical but in horizontal its not visisbale

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your divider with SizedBox and give height and width

```
          SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Divider(
                    thickness: 2,
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: not working in horizontal list view

Comment: Please add your current and expected output image

Comment: It's working, I have added output image, please check

Comment: is not working in listview.builder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Column` then you should wrap with `IntrinsicHeight` and for `Row` required `IntrinsicWidth` to show divider.

In your case you are using `Column` you should use `IntrinsicHeight`.

Try this code:

```
                IntrinsicHeight( <---------------- just add this widget
                child:Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: const [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                      width: 100,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: 10,topLeft: 10),
                          child: Text("admistraction")),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                     height: 50,
                     width:50
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 2,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    )),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 5),
                        child: Text(
                          "Start Learning",
                        )),
                  ],
                )),
```

Comment: Still not working .

Comment: Add `sizedBox` to abover `DIvider`. see I have edited changes in answer.

Comment: after wrapping with sizedBox it create space but divider line is not visible

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add Height to Divider it will work.
Just adding a small sample for reference.

The usage will be:

HorizontalOrLine(height: 10,label: "OR")

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class HorizontalOrLine extends StatelessWidget {
  const HorizontalOrLine({
    this.label,
    this.height,
  });

  final String label;
  final double height;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 15.0),
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: height,
            )),
      ),

      Text(label),

      Expanded(
        child: new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 10.0),
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: height,
            )),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: Divider(
            thickness: 2,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            ),
          ),
```

Try adding width to your divider like this

[image]