# Why Divider widget didn't work in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Although I add divider widget in my app, but in result
I don't see divider in my app. I don't know what happened.
And Just see nothing line for divider widget.
At first I see the divider, later I do some changes and then I add divider again but I can't see any divider.
Please help me.
Here is my code.

> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> ```
> class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
>   const SettingScreen({super.key});
>
>   @override
>   State<SettingScreen> createState() => _SettingScreenState();
> }
>
> class _SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen> {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       body: SafeArea(
>           child: Column(
>         children: [
>           Container(
>             width: double.infinity,
>             height: 100,
>             decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                 boxShadow: const [
>                   BoxShadow(
>                       color: Colors.black26,
>                       blurRadius: 90,
>                       offset: Offset(4, 9))
>                 ],
>                 gradient: LinearGradient(
>                     colors: [
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 148, 210),
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 160, 195),
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 134, 174, 207),
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 187, 212),
>                     ],
>                     begin: Alignment.topLeft,
>                     end: Alignment.topRight,
>                     stops: [0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1.4])),
>             child: Padding(
>               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
>               child: Row(children: [
>                 Text(
>                   "REL" + '\n' + "  ATE",
>                   style: TextStyle(
>                     color: Colors.white,
>                     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                     fontSize: 10,
>                     letterSpacing: 20,
>                   ),
>                 ),
>                 SizedBox(
>                   width: 130,
>                 ),
>                 Icon(
>                   Icons.skip_next_rounded,
>                   color: Colors.white,
>                   size: 50,
>                 ),
>               ]),
>             ),
>           ),
>           Stack(
>             clipBehavior: Clip.none,
>             children: [
>               Container(
>                 width: 300,
>                 height: 522,
>                 decoration:
>                     BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: const [
>                   BoxShadow(
>                     color: Colors.black,
>                     offset: Offset(1, 2),
>                     blurRadius: 50,
>                   )
>                 ]),
>               ),
>               Positioned(
>                 top: 10,
>                 right: 1,
>                 child: SizedBox(
>                   child: Container(
>                     // width: 500,
>                     child: Column(
>                       children: [
>                         Text(
>                           "SETTINGS",
>                           style: TextStyle(
>                               color: Colors.black,
>                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                               fontSize: 30,
>                               letterSpacing: 18),
>                         ),
>                         Padding(
>                           padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 150, top: 10),
>                           child: Text(
>                             "ACCOUNT",
>                             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
>                           ),
>                         ),
>                         Divider(
>                           color: Colors.grey,
>                         )
>                       ],
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>               )
>             ],
>           )
>         ],
>       )),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem by wrapping SizedBox.

> ```
>                    SizedBox(
>                                 width: 350,
>                                 height: 10,
>                                 child: Divider(
>                                   color: Colors.black,
>                                 ),
>
>                               ),
> ```

I get this solution from here [Divider is not visible in horizontal list view flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599790/divider-is-not-visible-in-horizontal-list-view-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

```
try this


class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SettingScreen> createState() => _SettingScreenState();
}

class _SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 90,
                      offset: Offset(4, 9))
                ],
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 148, 210),
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 160, 195),
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 134, 174, 207),
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 187, 212),
                    ],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.topRight,
                    stops: [0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1.4])),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: Row(children: [
                Text(
                  "REL" + '\n' + "  ATE",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 10,
                    letterSpacing: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 130,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.skip_next_rounded,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 50,
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 522,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    offset: Offset(1, 2),
                    blurRadius: 50,
                  )
                ]),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 10,
                right: 1,
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Container(
                    // width: 500,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "SETTINGS",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              letterSpacing: 18),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 150, top: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            "ACCOUNT",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                       
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
           Divider(
                   color: Colors.grey,
                    height:1)
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works or not?

Answer (score 0):

please add height inside divider.

Divider(
color: Colors.grey,
height: 1, // Set the height to make the divider visible
)

Comment: I try to add height as your advice but nothing changes.

Comment: add divider outside of stack widget